# Plot start-end time slots - matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, slots

I'm trying to plot time slots. I have two ndarrays of 'start' and 'end' points.
I want to draw it as chunks on a figure. Keep in mind that the chunks are not consecutive and there are gaps between the slots.

Until now I have tried to use patches:

```
for x_1 , x_2 in zip(s_data['begin'].values ,s_data['end'].values):
ax1.add_patch(Rectangle((x_1,0),x_2-x_1,0.5)) 
plt.show()
```

But its only giving me hald blue figure.

While I want something like this

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The approach is correct. You just need to scale the axes such that the complete plot is within its range.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"begin": [1,4,6,9], "end" : [3,5,8,12]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for x_1 , x_2 in zip(df['begin'].values ,df['end'].values):
    ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x_1,0),x_2-x_1,0.5))

ax.autoscale()
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

It is worth noting that matplotlib has a function [`broken_barh`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/broken_barh.html), which simplifies the creation of such charts.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"begin": [1,4,6,9], "end" : [3,5,8,12]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.broken_barh(list(zip(df["begin"].values, (df["end"] - df["begin"]).values)), (0, 0.5))

ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
```

Giving the same diagram as the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot the second way make much more sense